How to remove duplicate slashes from path to a file?
I have a path to a file that has duplicate slashes which would like to simplify.
For example, if I have the following:
/opt//bin//executable

I would like to get:
/opt/bin/executable


Can you add more context why and where you need to do this?  Usually the commandline just silently ignores the superflous slashes.

@markgraf, I would like to do it from a shell or a makefile.

Using POSIX tr:
$ echo /opt//bin//executable | tr -s /
/opt/bin/executable

GNU tr has a long-form option that does the same thing: tr --squeeze-repeats.

This would remove a double // at the start of the pathname, too, which may cause the pathname to be interpreted differently depending on what's using it.

Good point, see On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?

The simple answer is
setopt extended_glob
f=/opt//bin//executable
f=${f//\/\/##//}
print -rl -- $f

This uses the ${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT} form of parameter expansion. The pattern is //##, using the ## glob operator which means “one or more of the preceding character or group”. This glob operator requires the extended_glob option. Because the pattern is delimited by slashes, you need to protect the slashes in the pattern with a backslash, which makes the result awkward.
There is a corner case: on some systems, a path with exactly two leading slashes has a special meaning. The following code handles this special case.
setopt extended_glob
f=//special//bin//executable
case $f in
  //|//[^/]*) f=//${${f#//}//\/\/##//};;
  *) f=${f//\/\/##//};;
esac
print -rl -- $f

You may also want to remove a trailing slash (taking care not to break the edge case of the root directory):
if [[ $f = *[^/]*/ ]]; then f=${f%/}; fi

If you also want to simplify ./ and foo/.. segments, the a modifier does this, and also constructs an absolute path.
print -r -- $f:a


Since this is tagged zsh, you could expand a variable containing the path using the a modifier, which will treat the variable as a path and canonicalize it:
printf '%s\n' "${var:a}"

% var='/opt//bin//executable'
printf '%s\n' "${var:a}"
/opt/bin/executable

It will work even for paths including one or more leading / trailing slashes:
% var='//opt//bin//executable//'
printf '%s\n' "${var:a}"
/opt/bin/executable

Note that this will work as expected only for absolute paths. Expanding a variable containing a relative path will result in a canonical path to the stored path relatively to the current working directory:
% var='opt//bin//executable//'
printf '%s\n' "${var:a}"
/home/user/opt/bin/executable


One (of many) possible approach is to use the csh-style substitute modifier ($var:s://:/) combined with the f modifier which repeats the substitution until there's no modification:
$ file=/opt//bin/////executable
$ print -r - $file:fs://:/
/opt/bin/executable


Using python
P=/opt//bin//executable
RP=$(python3 -c "import pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(\"$P\"))")

❯ echo $RP    
/opt/bin/executable

Python seems to keep the leading double slashes as it is.
❯ P=//opt//bin//executable                                      

❯ RP=$(python3 -c "import pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(\"$P\"))")

❯ echo $RP                                                      
//opt/bin/executable


Update
If the path is coming from untrusted source, pass it as cli arg instead.
P=/opt//bin//executable
RP=$(python3 -c "import pathlib, sys; print(pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]))" "$P")

❯ echo $RP
/opt/bin/executable


Embedding the value of a shell variable in the code argument of some interpreter is a big No!No! from a security point of view. That introduces arbitrary command execution vulnerabilities. You should pass the value instead via a separate (non-code) argument (retrieved in sys.argv) or the environment.

Also handling arbitrary file paths in python3 is generally messy, here you'd probably be better of invoking it in the C locale to avoid character encoding issues, and command substitution removes all trailing newline characters, so in the end you'd need something like LC_ALL=C python3 -c 'import sys, pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1]), end = "\0")' "$P" | IFS= read -rd '' RP

Good point about security. Updated to show an example for that. I would skip handling locale and trailing new line issues to keep it simple. For a filesystem path, it would be very rare for paths to contain any new lines.
